# How to join according to value of a field on mysql

Tags: sql, database, join

I have user table in my database and there is a user_type field, which has 0 or 1. if the value is 0, I want it to be joined with teacher table if not with student table.

Is it possible?

Comment: `if not with user table`, do you have two user tables or do you wish for it to join to itself?

Comment: i want it to join itself each correct tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use cross apply or a CTE but as you dont specify the DB your using this should work as a generic solution

```
Select t1.fields,t2.fields
From user_table t1
LEFT JOIN teacher_table t2 
ON t1.ID=t2.ID 
and t1.user_type_field=0
UNION ALL
Select t1.fields,t2.fields
From user_table t1
LEFT JOIN student_table t2 
ON t1.ID=t2.ID 
and t1.user_type_field=1
```

Comment: This assumes the `teacher_table` & `student_table` have the same number of columns and the same data types (as it uses a union)

Answer (score 1):

If both your `teacher` and `user` table have same columns and you don't want duplicate records,use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`

```
Select *
From user_table u
LEFT JOIN teacher_table t 
ON u.ID=t.ID 
and u.user_type_field=0
UNION
Select *
From user_table u
LEFT JOIN student_table t 
ON u.ID=t.ID 
and u.user_type_field=1
```

> Replace the `*` with whatever fields you need to select as selecting
>   all the fields may hit your performance very badly.

Answer (score 0):

For easy to understand, you totally do it in your code-behind.
E.g. using Enum for that field.